# Execute contract without gas on parity private network

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, gas

is it real to execute contract without gas?

I develop app on parity private network, in what user can register account, after registration he must receive coins from admin address.

But new users (new addrress on private netowkr) can't execute contract, because they don't have coins for pay gas.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to set the gas price to 0.

Comment: Where in parity i can set gas price to zerO?

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you don't need *coins* for making transaction, you need *ether*.

### Recommended solution:

After creating an account, get that account address, and give balance to that address in the genesis file. You should be able to find detailed description of process in [wiki/demo PoA tutorial](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Demo-PoA-tutorial)

### Your requested solution:

While starting parity, start it with `--gasprice 0` option. These configurations are described in detail in [wiki/configuring-parity](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Configuring-Parity)